# Multiple Cloudera Hadoop Tables in Tableau

Tags: hadoop, tableau-api, cloudera

I am trying to create a viz which uses a number of unrelated data sources all coming from various different tables in Hadoop.

When I create a connection for another Table, I am using the Same Schema for finding that new table but regardless of that I need to create a new connection. This is a problem since to render all charts in my Viz (containing about 250 charts) I need to sign in to all those tables. Therefore

**Question  1**: Is there a way to connect multiple tables in the same schema while connecting with Cloudera Hadoop on Tableau in order to have a single sign on for all the tables ?

**Question  2**: My Hadoop Tables frequently time-out and the connection gets disconnected frequently. Is there a way to prevent disconnection with Hadoop so that I don't have to sign on repeatedly?

Comment: Assuming you are using Impala, you can create a `VIEW` there of many tables, then query that from Tableau

Comment: I am using HIVE. I have all the tables I want present in HDFS which I just want to pull to Tableau. There are multiple such tables for which I need to login multiple times !!

Comment: Again, if you defined a VIEW, you login one time. And all the tables are joined in Hive, not from Tableau